# Bathroom Light Going out

Tags: lighting, bathroom

So I have a Recessed Retrofit Downlight in the shower that began flickering and now is mostly dark, although sometimes it will go on. I removed it and here are the parts:

Recessed Retrofit Downlight Model DLS02-06A27D1E-WH-F1

This is the part that seems to hold the bulb and is flush against the ceiling when installed. It's held in by two springs.

The other part I can see is:

Dimmable Constant Current LED Driver Model JW03-013-D-047-I-N

This has a black and white wire attached to an orange female plastic thing that clips into a male plastic thing in the ceiling, and another set of wires that looks like it must run into the bulb itself.

My question is what part of this do I need to replace? Can I just go to Lowe's and pick out the part?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I got impatient and went to Lowe's with the fixture. The lighting guy there said the problem was the ballast (I didn't even know there was such a thing for LED) and that replacing the fixture was the right play. It cost about $13, and I reinstalled it and everything is fine now.

Comment: I would make the screw in adapter is snug in the original socket. If it is snug, I would screw this into another lamp and see if it works if it still won't light the driver has probably failed and usually the light has to be replaced. I would check to see if it's under warrantee.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm glad you found an answer; would you add it as an answer to your question? That way future visitors may be helped by your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got impatient and went to Lowe's with the fixture. The lighting guy there said the problem was the ballast (I didn't even know there was such a thing for LED) and that replacing the fixture was the right play. It cost about $13, and I reinstalled it and everything is fine now.